# Regular Expression for Range chinese chars and selected groups of chars

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get all Chinese sentences from strings with addtional group of chars like [NAME] and [PLACE].

I have this string

```
<DisplayName>凡人战争</DisplayName>
<Desc>[NAME]赶到[PLACE]，发现战火正燃，此地百姓饱受战争之苦。</Desc>
<Display>劝停战争</Display>  
<OKResult><![CDATA[me:AddMsg(XT("[NAME]以仙法摄走两军首领，一番劝戒，迫使他们停止了战争 ...
```

and I want find

```
凡人战争
[NAME]赶到[PLACE]，发现战火正燃，此地百姓饱受战争之苦
[NAME]以仙法摄走两军首领，一番劝戒，迫使他们停止了战争，消弭了这场祸事
此举手段温和，虽无人知晓，但却顺应天道，[NAME]获得了一些功德
```

I know for chinese chars regex is `[\u4e00-\u9fff\uFF0C]+`
and for group chars `(\u005BNAME\u005D)` and `(\u005BPLACE\u005D)` but how to combine this.

I try this way written in python

```
Array_of_words = re.findall(r'[\u4e00-\u9fff\uFF0C(\u005BNAME\u005D)(\u005BPLACE\u005D)]+', text)
```

But additionally marks single letters and brackets like this:

```
['N', 'N', '凡人战争', 'N', '[NAME]赶到[PLACE]，发现战火正燃，此地百姓饱受战争之苦', '劝停战争', '[C', 'A', 'A[', 'A', 'M', '(', '(', '[NAME]以仙法摄走两军首领，一番劝戒，迫使他们停止了战争，消弭了这场祸事', '此举手段温和，虽无人知晓，但却顺应天道，[NAME]获得了一些功德', '))', 'A', 'P', '(', '(', '))', '()', ']]']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.findall(r'(?:\[(?:PLACE|NAME)]|[\u4e00-\u9fff\uFF0C])+', text)
```

*Details*

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `\[(?:PLACE|NAME)]` - `[`, then either `PLACE` or `NAME` and then `]`
  - `|` - or
  - `[\u4e00-\u9fff\uFF0C]` - a Chinese char pattern of yours
- `)+` - end of the group, match one or more occurrences.

To match any uppercase ASCII letters inside square brackets, replace `\[(?:PLACE|NAME)]` with `\[[A-Z]+]`.